# Zero divisor and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a matrix that is both invertible and is a zero-divisor? That is, $A^{-1}$ exists, but $\exists B$ such that $AB=0$?

Comment: No, this is impossible.  Suppose that $AB=0$ and $CA=I$.  Now, what is $CAB$?

Answer (score 6):

Zero divisors in a ring with identity can't be units. If you suppose $xy=0$ with $x$ invertible and $y\neq 0$, then
$$0=x^{-1}0=x^{-1}(xy)=(x^{-1}x)y = y$$ contrary to the assumption that $y\neq 0$.